# SQL syntax issue for a nested count query for count?

Tags: sql, oracle

For the below query i am facing the Missing expresssions error in Oracle SQL Developer,
Can someone help me with this issue.

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEC.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_DET.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT MB.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT OD.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID)
   FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.SECURITY_SCHEDULE SEC_SCH
     ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID     =SEC_SCH.MSD_SECURITY_ID
    WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT main.MSD_SECURITY_ID
         FROM SCHEMA2.Positions main
          WHERE main.QUANTITY != 0
          AND systimestamp    >= main.eff_from_dt
          AND main.eff_to_dt   > systimestamp
          AND systimestamp    >= main.asrt_from_dt
          AND main.asrt_to_dt  > systimestamp
     ) 

FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC
JOIN SCHEMA.SECURITY_DETAIL SEC_DET
ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID = SEC_DET.MSD_SECURITY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.MUNI_BOND MB
ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID=MB.MSD_SECURITY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.OPTION_DETAIL OD
ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID =OD.MSD_SECURITY_ID
WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT main.MSD_SECURITY_ID
  FROM SCHEMA2.Positions main
  WHERE main.QUANTITY != 0
  AND systimestamp    >= main.eff_from_dt
  AND main.eff_to_dt   > systimestamp
  AND systimestamp    >= main.asrt_from_dt
  AND main.asrt_to_dt  > systimestamp
  ) ;
```

Error

ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 365 Column: 3

Comment: I have updated the above query to use Parenthesis nut now i am getting this error
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 365 Column: 11

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries *must* be wrapped in parenthesis.  Once you add them, Oracle should stop complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries do need to be in parentheses.  The subquery could probably be written just using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` rather than a nested subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEC.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
       COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_DET.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
       COUNT(DISTINCT MB.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
       COUNT(DISTINCT OD.ERROR_GROUP_ID),
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID)
        FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC LEFT OUTER JOIN
             SCHEMA.SECURITY_SCHEDULE SEC_SCH
             ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID = SEC_SCH.MSD_SECURITY_ID
         WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN ( <values>)  
        )  . . .
```

Note that this has a very small semantic difference from your query.  This does not count `NULL` values, whereas your version does.  You can get the same semantics by doing:

```
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID) + MAX(CASE WHEN SEC_SCH.ERROR_GROUP_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM SCHEMA.SECURITY SEC LEFT OUTER JOIN
             SCHEMA.SECURITY_SCHEDULE SEC_SCH
             ON SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID = SEC_SCH.MSD_SECURITY_ID
         WHERE SEC.MSD_SECURITY_ID IN ( <values>)  
        )  . . .
```

It is unusual to be using a subquery for this purpose.  I wonder if you can use analytic functions instead.

Comment: I am still getting an Error, Unfortunately i cannot paste the query in comments as its too large So i am adding an answer instead for Experts to see.